# Why a large proportion of a bank’s balance sheet would fall into either Current Assset or Liabilities, while defining Working Captial?

Tags: banking, stock-valuation

In **"Valuing Financial Service Firms" by Aswath Damodaran** he wrote

> With working capital, we run into a different problem. If we define working capital as the difference between current assets and current liabilities, a large proportion of a bank’s balance sheet would fall into one or the other of these categories. Changes in this number can be both large and volatile and may have no relationship to reinvestment for future growth.

**Why do we have such distribution where one side has more (things, I don't what to term them i.e. assets and liabilities in general) than other?** Is it because how an asset or a liability is defined when used in the context of Bank or any Fin. Serv. Firm?

BTW to just clear things out. This is not homework assignment, I am a Physics student but reading this paper out of curiosity but since I lack the formal background in the subject, May be I got stuck on couple sentences. Appreciate I your help, so that I remaining part.

[image]

Comment: When you deposit $1 at the bank, the bank has balance sheet assets of $1 (because it has your $1) and liabilities of $1 (because it owes you your $1), and you have an IOU for your $1.  Banks are different from most companies because they’re selling you custodianship off your money and utility of financial services like a debit card, and the bank will lend out your $1 to 10 more people, and since they’re allowed to do that, governments (which insure the IOU you have for your $1) heavily regulate the banking business.

Comment: @quid By $1 to 10 more people, you meant creation using Fractional Reserve, Right?
And lets say hypothetically CRR is at 10% then every $1 deposited to the bank, bank can lend max $10 hence it has more liabilities than assets. Am I correct?